# How to control the iphone power button programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiswitch, ios-frameworks, uievent

I want to control the iphone device programmatically.

1. I mean,when user want to switch off the phone one alert message will come.it will
     ask the password then only the operation will work.
2. when user delete the app from the his/her device one alert will come and ask the
      password for the security reasons.

   what type of the frame works required for handling the power button as well as the app
     control on the device.

Comment: You cannot do it with a non-jailbroken device.

Comment: once see this it may help you       http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/71616-whats-the-protocol-for-power-button-being-pressed.html

Answer (score 5):

> 1. I mean,when user want to switch off the phone one alert message will come.it will ask the password then only the operation will work.

You can't

> 1. when user delete the app from the his/her device one alert will come and ask the password for the security reasons.

You can't.

But you could use [Apple's Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12) to configure iOS devices with profiles of you company. This way the user won't be able to uninstall the app.

The Apple configurator can do lots of other things as well. Think about setting up restrictions, accounts, password, security and other things on the device.

There are even Over The Air Updates possible of you use a Mobile Device Management Server or Service